# Solving particle on a ring problem using momentum eigenvalue equation instead of energy eigenvalue equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics

I have read somewhere that for [particle on a ring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_in_a_ring) problem you don't have to solve eigenvalue equation $H\psi=E\psi$ you can instead solve eigenvalue equation $P\psi=p\psi$ where P is momentum operator. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't it just generally true that in the absence of any potential, the momentum eigenfunctions are also energy eigenfunctions? In other words, when there is no potential, (in the right units)

$$ H = p^2/2m + V(x) = p^2/2m
$$

Since the Hamiltonian is proportional to the momentum operator squared, it's easy to see that any eigenket of the momentum operator having eigenvalue $p$ will be an eigenket of the momentum operator with eigenvalue $ p^2/2m$. It turns out that the momentum eigenkets (and linear combinations thereof) form the complete solution set of the particle on a ring problem.